# How can I make Iridescence material In unity?

Tags: unity, shaders, materials

One of the characters of the Dota2 that Is called [Nyx Assassin](https://dota2.gamepedia.com/Nyx_Assassin) has an interesting material effect If you look at the body and feet you can see this effect.It looks like [poily/polluted water](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/64613/rendering-oily-polluted-water).I like to know how can I make something like that In unity.

[image: Nyx assassin]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found same question [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1605/iridescence-in-cycles) and I could make Iridecence In unity
.

you can download this shader from [my github](https://github.com/smkplus/Iridescence).

[image]

[My tutorial About Iridescence Shader](https://www.patreon.com/posts/18699278)

> Iridescence (also known as goniochromism) is the phenomenon of certain surfaces that appear to gradually change colour as the angle of view or the angle of illumination changes. Examples of iridescence include soap bubbles, butterfly wings and seashells, as well as certain minerals. It is often created by structural coloration (microstructures that interfere with light).
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iridescence

[image: iridescent shader]

[image: Image1]

## Prototyping with Blender

[image: Image2]

## Simple Iridescence Shader

[image: sf_iridescence_512018]

## Adding distortion to Iridescence

[image: sf_iridescence_512018]